# How to use bootstrap for pictures or videos to adjust to screen size when on mobile or tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website created in bootstrap so when I go on mobile or tablet the navbar and all the other stuff adjust to the screen size, but I have added 3 boxes and 2 youtube videos and I would like them to adjust to the screen size when I go on mobile or tablet. It looks fine on my desktop but when i look on my mobile the videos and the boxes are out the screen.
Can someone please help me get this done as quick as possible please, it's very important to get it done. Can someone please walk me step by step on how to do this?
Here are some screenshots:

HTML For the 3 boxes which are just images

```
<div class="img1">
<a href="link"><img src="img"></a>
</div>

<div class="img2">
<a href="link"><img src="img"></a>
</div>

<div class="img3">
<a href="link"><img src="img"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img1 {
 position: relative;
 left: 290px;
 bottom: -20px;
}

.img3 {
 position: relative;
 left: 578px;
 bottom: 101px;
}

.img2 {
 position: relative;
 left: 865px;
 bottom: 222px;
}
```

Thats how it looks on my desktop

[image]

And thats how it looks on a tablet size, you can probably imagine how it looks on a mobile

[image]

If you would like take a look yourself at http://www.praga-light.de, the youtube videos look great just how I wanted them to be but the 3 boxes when you resize the browser they just go out of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need youtube video change width size on mobile right?

You add a div wrap to video code,

```
    <div class="ResponsiveVideoWrapper">
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CqVqlcBQGYw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.ResponsiveVideoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}

.ResponsiveVideoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didnt work the way I needed it to work, on my desktop the videos got really small, but yeah when I switch to mobile size or tablet size the videos adjust but they are still out of frame

Comment: You do not have any code on you question so i can not very understand you problem. But this thing is easy, responsive is ablout set the width 100%. If you video too small, that mean the father div of video too small. Just change it width.

Comment: Ok, I played around with the css and got it to work how I needed it to, but what about the 3 boxes I have, they are just Images

Comment: 3 image in one line, that mean 1 image have 30% width. Set them width to 30%

Comment: Ok, I set them the width to 30% on all the images but it doesnt do anything

Comment: wrap them in one div, set it div width 100%, set image display inline-block, float left and width 30%. I you send some code to here, i can tell you easyer,

Comment: Hello @Tran I did what you told me and it didn't do anything at all, I will put the code I have on my 3 images right now

Answer (score 1):

**I have create pure bootstrap grid system. Please try this code**

```css
.portfolio-item {
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!------Strat html code-------->
<div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <a href="#">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ePbKGoIGAXY"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item">

    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_FOSmVKg.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <a href="#">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ePbKGoIGAXY"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!------End html code-------->
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for a reply, thank you for taking your time to create this grid system but my 3 boxes are all vertical and I need them to be going all horizantaly under the youtube video

Comment: you need to horizontal div. replace col-xs-12 class to col-xs-4. I updated code. check it

Answer (score 0):

About image block, you do not need there div, here is better html

```
<div class="img1">
    <a href="/"><img src="n.png"></a>
    <a href="/"><img src="n.png"></a>
    <a href="/"><img src="n.png"></a>
</div>

<style>
.img1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.img1 a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
<style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but how do I make the boxes be in line with the video again, it's all shifted to left and a little up behind the video, take a look at http://www.praga-light.de I have updated it.

Comment: I think you need to move div.boxes to inside div.col-md-9 and below div.ResponsiveVideoWrapper:

`<div class="ResponsiveVideoWrapper"></div>
<div class="ResponsiveVideoWrapper coated-collection"></div>
<div class="boxes">
    <a href="/"><img src="/"></a>
    <a href="/"><img src="/"></a>
    <a href="/"><img src="/"></a>
</div></div>`

Comment: Ok, ive updated it on my site, but now 2 boxes are in line and the third one is at the bottom of 2 boxes

Comment: Just adjust the width of a and image

Comment: css of course, change 30% to whatever you want!

'.boxes a {
    width: 30%;
}
.boxes a img {
    width: 100%;
}
'

Comment: Man, I don't know what else to do, I did what you told me, now it looks great on my Iphone but the boxes are messed up on the desktop

Comment: You just copy the code i write above in to your css, you done ! Here:

`.boxes a { width: 30%; } .boxes a img { width: 100%; }`

My god, you need learn some css before you do this.

Comment: Yeah well thats the problem, I don't have much knowledge to this, I was just put down to a computer and told that this must be done. And where did you get the .boxes a img from? Where did the img came from you dont have that in your css.

Comment: i'm go to your site and write the code base your have on the site. You just add this css to your styles.css.

Comment: The css has been there the whole time just when I add the width 30% the boxes go on top of each other in one line and when adjust the browser size they go out of screen

Comment: They happen because you do not add `.boxes a img { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Well, I guess that will have to do for now, thanks man, your a legend.